# Minecraft Forge 1.8 Mod Not Compiling With "GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'forge'"

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I made a mod and I am trying to run `gradle build`, but I keep running into issues. I've looked everywhere for a solution. Here is what happens when I run `gradle build --stacktrace`, the issue seems to be in the `apply plugin:'net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge'` part of the `build.gradle` file:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Minecraft\Desktop\Minecraft_Mod\Forge\build.gradle' line: 15

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Forge'.
> 'org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskOutputs org.gradle.api.internal.TaskOutputsInternal.dir(java.lang.Object)'

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Forge'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:136)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:277)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:250)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:310)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:291)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:249)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:721)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:151)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:41)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:67)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:46)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:56)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.prepareProjects(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:226)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:163)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:148)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:77)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:49)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskOutputs org.gradle.api.internal.TaskOutputsInternal.dir(java.lang.Object)'
        at net.minecraftforge.gradle.user.UserBasePlugin.makeRunTasks(UserBasePlugin.java:856)
        at net.minecraftforge.gradle.user.UserBasePlugin.applyPlugin(UserBasePlugin.java:160)
        at net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.BasePlugin.apply(BasePlugin.java:201)
        at net.minecraftforge.gradle.common.BasePlugin.apply(BasePlugin.java:89)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginTarget.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginTarget.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginTarget.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.addPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:177)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.access$100(DefaultPluginManager.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager$AddPluginBuildOperation.run(DefaultPluginManager.java:272)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.lambda$doApply$0(DefaultPluginManager.java:157)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:156)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:136)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:160)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:183)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at build_drsp1hph1wapkxwo7nf16a2pv.run(C:\Users\Minecraft\Desktop\Minecraft_Mod\Forge\build.gradle:15)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
        ... 139 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 662ms
```

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
// For those who want the bleeding edge
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            name = "forge"
            url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.1-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge'

/*
// for people who want stable - not yet functional for MC 1.8.8 - we require the forgegradle 2.1 snapshot
plugins {
    id "net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge" version "2.0.2"
}
*/
version = "v.1.0.1-mc1.8.9"
group= "com.javamonk.universemod" // http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html
archivesBaseName = "universemod"

sourceSets {
    main {
        java { srcDirs = ["$projectDir/src/main/java"] }
        resources { srcDirs = ["$projectDir/src/main/resources"] }
    }
}

minecraft {
    version = "1.8.9-11.15.1.1722"
    runDir = "run"
    
    // the mappings can be changed at any time, and must be in the following format.
    // snapshot_YYYYMMDD   snapshot are built nightly.
    // stable_#            stables are built at the discretion of the MCP team.
    // Use non-default mappings at your own risk. they may not allways work.
    // simply re-run your setup task after changing the mappings to update your workspace.
    mappings = "stable_20"
    // makeObfSourceJar = false // an Srg named sources jar is made by default. uncomment this to disable.
}

dependencies {
    // you may put jars on which you depend on in ./libs
    // or you may define them like so..
    //compile "some.group:artifact:version:classifier"
    //compile "some.group:artifact:version"
      
    // real examples
    //compile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'  // adds buildcraft to the dev env
    //compile 'com.googlecode.efficient-java-matrix-library:ejml:0.24' // adds ejml to the dev env

    // the 'provided' configuration is for optional dependencies that exist at compile-time but might not at runtime.
    //provided 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'

    // the deobf configurations:  'deobfCompile' and 'deobfProvided' are the same as the normal compile and provided,
    // except that these dependencies get remapped to your current MCP mappings
    //deobfCompile 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'
    //deobfProvided 'com.mod-buildcraft:buildcraft:6.0.8:dev'

    // for more info...
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html
    // http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html

}

processResources
{
    // this will ensure that this task is redone when the versions change.
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    // replace stuff in mcmod.info, nothing else
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'
                
        // replace version and mcversion
        expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
    }
        
    // copy everything else, thats not the mcmod.info
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
}
```

Here is my `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
#Mon Sep 14 12:28:28 PDT 2015
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-all.zip
```

My `JAVA_HOME` points to `jdk-16.0.1` at the moment, but I also tried it with `JAVA_HOME` pointed to `jdk1.8.0_101`, but neither seemed to work. I've tried downloading different versions of Java JDK, I've changed the urls all over the place, I've even tried to download the latest version of MCreator and steal their `build.gradle` files, but I'm running into the same issues there too. What can I do?